# List all pages part of DotNetNuke framework

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need list of all the pages that DotNetNuke uses as part of its functionality like:

```
/Login.aspx
/Admin/*
/LinkClick.aspx
etc...
```

How can I find this information?

EDIT: So far I have found:

```
/Default.aspx
/KeepAlive.aspx
/ErrorPage.aspx
/Login.aspx
/Logoff.aspx
/LinkClick.aspx
/Rss.aspx
/Sitemap.aspx
/*.captcha.aspx
/User.aspx
/Admin/*
/Host/*
/DesktopModule/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to /sitemap.aspx on your site, that will list off public pages.

You could take a look at the web.config, the handlers section, you can also check out the SITEURLS.config file, and ultimately you may simply need to do a command line search for .ASPX in the DNN directory itself, to get a full list.

It is possible for Custom modules to use their own ASPX pages, which will vary by module.

Comment: Thanks you that really helps me find more pages.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Most "pages" in DNN are dynamically generated, not physical ASPX files.

Comment: I am trying to add some basic URL seo, lowercase, redirect to extensionless, rewrite to .aspx etc but it breaks functionality for DNN. I want to exclude the DNN urls

Comment: If you are using DNN 7.1, there is now build in URL functionality which allows you to customize URLs for pages, remove ASPX, etc.

Comment: Upgrades aren't difficult to do in DNN, though you should backup/test before doing it in production.